# Use of non-amd jquery plugins with requirejs without modifying them?

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I recently searched a lot on use of non-amd jquery code with requirejs but couldn't find a proper way to do it.

To be more specific, I want to use pana-accordion.js found at below mentioned url.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/Horizontal-Accordion-Slider-Plugin-with-jQuery-Pana-Accordion.html

But the problem is that it is not amd aware and nor it exports anything out of it.So far I have created my `custom.phtml` and called it on homepage through admin area.Below is my `custom.phtml`

```
<div class="pana-accordion" id="accordion">
  <div class="pana-accordion-wrap">
    <div class="pana-accordion-item" style="background-color: #F44336"><img width="500" height="300" src="https://unsplash.it/500/300?image=57" /></div>
    <div class="pana-accordion-item" style="background-color: #2196F3"><img width="500" height="300" src="https://unsplash.it/500/300?image=49" /></div>
    <div class="pana-accordion-item" style="background-color: #4CAF50"><img width="500" height="300" src="https://unsplash.it/500/300?image=39" /></div>
    <div class="pana-accordion-item" style="background-color: #FF9800"><img width="500" height="300" src="https://unsplash.it/500/300?image=29" /></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','panaaccordion'],function($, accordion) {
                accordion.init({
                    id: 'accordion',
                });
    })
</script>
```

And Here is configuration for `pana-accordion.js` javascript module in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    'map': {
        '*': {
            'panaaccordion': 'js/pana-accordion'
        }
    },
    'shim': {
        'panaaccordion': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'accordion'
        }
    }
}
```

Below is some code lines for pana-acordion plugin

```
var accordion= {
    init: function(options){
        var that=this;
        options = $.extend(true,{
            expandWidth: 500,
            itemWidth: 100,
            extpand: 0,
            autoPlay: true,
            delay: 3000,
            animateTime: 400,
            borderWidth: 1,
            autoPlay: true,
            deviator: 30,
            bounce:"-50px"
        },options);
    .....
```

As you can see, it doesn't wrap code inside `define()` nor it exports or return anything.Rather accordion object is declared globally.

So far I have following questions (those marked as bold sorry for bad formatting but I am trying to improve it).

If I wrap the code inside define like below,

```
  define(['jquery'],function($){
            //pana-accordion plugin code
            });
```

Still, there is an error in console that says  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` even though I created exports entry in shim configuration.
But error resolves when I finally write return statement after accordion object.

```
return accordion;
```

**What is purpose of using shim if we have to manually write return statement from plugin for object for example?**

**Second, Do I have to write whole path for shim configuration? If I map alias `panaaccordion` for file located at `'js/pana-accordion'`, still I have to use `'js/pana-accordion'` for shim configuration otherwise there are some loading order issues.**

**Third- Can I use such non-amd plugins with requirejs without modifying a single line from them?? If yes, How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento already have accordion in lib 
you can take a look at here 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html
It's ready to use and full compatible for magento. You can extend it and customize to your widget.
But if you need integrate your lib you can do your way like above with need setup shim and depend config. Also you will need define wrap your plugin 
Lastly I don't think you can use non-amd plugins without modify it

Here is lib edited to work with magento 2
https://gist.github.com/mrtuvn/f65ae7d460ebf11c9d04fcb31a04e32c

Comment: OK but why do we need to write whole path in shim config even if we mapped panaAccordion module id for it? Why can't we just write `panaAccordion` instead of `js/accordion/pana-accordion` inside shim?

Comment: OK but are we spposed to rewrite every external lib to be able to integrate in magento ? I'm asking because we had some scripts in CMS that needed to be integrated to code since they depended on JQuery

Comment: No, you don't have to modify any single thing in libraries; you can use the `path` config attribute which works with all libraries, not just AMD-compatible ones -- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs.html